# what is this component BJJ?

Tags: identification

I didn't understand what is this component it is connected to [AD8551](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8551_8552_8554.pdf) i think that input pins HCSH and HCSL

[image: BJJ]  [image]

Comment: whats a serial high/low?

Comment: It's a **B**ipolar **J**unction **J**ansistor.

Comment: I agree , this circuit has a voltage gain of 20x on the current shunt  voltage input and appears to be AC coupled then attenuated perhaps by an external load R for AC current servo regulation of current in some larger configuration to smoothen the response of torque for example and load disturbances on current. A typical shunt may  be <=100mV so this could produce +/-2V output at some DC current but later DC biased to Vcc/2 on a single supply or attenuated by a load R to say +/-1V about Vcc/2. ( maybe)

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd) website that lists component markings, one possible match for the part is the [INA193AIDBV](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/i/n/ina193-ina198_rg_ti.pdf) current shunt (the pin-out is identical).

The two connections you have labelled as "HC Serial High/Low" are more likely to be "High-Current Shunt High/Low", and the the AD8551 is simply buffering the output (after the RC high-pass filter).

Without more information it's impossible to say for certain, but your circuit is likely sensing transients in a current.

Comment: https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32827057120.html?pid=808_0000_0131&spm=a2g0n.search-amp.list.32827057120 okey i find it thanks